# Make XML+CSS file content editable in firefox

Tags: css, xml, firefox, contenteditable

I have a XML document that I want do show in Firefox together with an assigned CSS file. I want to enable edit/design mode in firedox to enable the user to edit the text content. Same like contenteditable="true" would do for HTML content. Is this possible with XML+CSS content?

sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="sample.css" ?>
<doc>
    <red>red text</red>
    <blue>blue text</blue>
    <green>and... green text</green>
</doc>
```

sample.css

```
red {
    display: block;
    color: red;
}

blue {
    display: block;
    color: blue;
}

green {
    display: block;
    color: green;
}
```

Thanks,
Ingo

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomlish. Are you trying to build a firefox extension? Firefox extensions can work with XUL and CSS in order to do what you are describing.

Comment: I want to build a WYSIWYG Editor for XML files and use Firefox for the rendering. Loading, saving and other logic is build around Firefox by integration layer. So the only thing I need is to bring Firefox into edit mode to allow user to edit text and to get the text caret to appear. See example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_contenteditable